# Can I use DynamicParameters with Template and have a return parameter in dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

The system I am currently working on uses Stored Procedures for all data access.  I'm looking into Dapper at the moment (so far it looks great) but I was wondering if I can use a DynamicParameters object created using a Template but make one of the parameters an output param.  For example:

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPerson
  @ID int Output,
  @Name varchar(100),
  @DOB DateTime2
AS
--INSERT STATEMENT

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

POCO:

```
internal class Person
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
var procParams = new DynamicParameters(person);
connection.Execute("InsertPerson", procParams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

// This is where i'm having the issue, can it be done?
person.ID = procParams.Get<int>("ID");
```

Current I receive an error because the key was not found.  Is there a way to get the ID output parameter without manually setting up all of the stored procs parameters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a quick tweak, `Add` now *replaces* the value from a template, allowing:

```
public void TestProcWithOutParameter()
{
    connection.Execute(
        @"CREATE PROCEDURE #TestProcWithOutParameter
@ID int output,
@Foo varchar(100),
@Bar int
AS
SET @ID = @Bar + LEN(@Foo)");
    var obj = new
    { // this could be a Person instance etc
        ID = 0,
        Foo = "abc",
        Bar = 4
    };
    var args = new DynamicParameters(obj);
    args.Add("ID", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
    connection.Execute("#TestProcWithOutParameter", args,
                 commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    args.Get<int>("ID").IsEqualTo(7);
}
```

Is that close enough? You can also use `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`, of either a pre-existing value or a new value. Note it does **not** update directly back into the original template; the value must be fetched from the `DynamicParameters` instance (as shown).

Comment: I assume the value could be automatically updated by using the `.Output<T>(T, Expression<Func<T, object>>)` method on `DynamicParameters` right?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the constructor for `DynamicParameters` to specify a template object you will still need to specify that `@ID` is an output parameter. At first, via the template, it will be set to `ParameterDirection.Input`. Once you add it, it will be overridden to have the updated values, then you can get the value by the parameter name as follows:

```
procParams.Add("@ID", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
// ... execute ...
person.ID = procParams.Get<int>("@ID");
```

I was able to get this working and used your classes and code, in addition to what I showed above.

**EDIT:** as discussed in the comments, the stored procedure doesn't accept more arguments than it has declared. Thus, an alternate approach is to ditch the stored procedure and resort to some inline SQL. When you use a query Dapper will ignore any parameters given to it that aren't specified in the SQL statement. This is a work-around to tackle this issue:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Person (Name, DOB) VALUES (@Name, @DOB) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
decimal id = conn.Query<decimal>(sql, procParams).First();
person.ID = (int)id;
```

Note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns a decimal, not an int.

Another idea, which I think isn't ideal, is to modify the Dapper code and add a `Remove` method to the `DynamicParameters` class to remove undesired parameters. This doesn't save you much though since you'll still spend time specifying which parameters to remove all for the sake of making a stored procedure happy. If you decide to implement this remember that case matters when specifying the key to remove from the `parameters` dictionary.

Comment: I tried this already but I get an exception "Procedure or function InsertPerson has too many arguments specified.". Sorry, should have put that in the question.

Comment: @Fermin the exception you're getting occurs when the parameters contain more arguments than the number of arguments declared in the stored procedure. Since you're passing in `person` as a template to the `DynamicParameters` constructor all properties on the `Person` class have a parameter generated for it. So I suspect you have more properties than just `ID`, `Name`, and `DOB` in your class. If this is the case then I think you'll need to specify the parameters yourself by adding them as I've shown above.

Comment: I suspected as much, I am trying to write a generic DataAccess class and as such was trying to avoid specifying the parameters individually.

Comment: @Ahmed thanks for your thoughts on this; as it happens, `Add` is already a *replace*, so in many ways it should have already worked, however the *template* is treated differently to the explicit parameters for various reasons. With a quick tweak, `Add` can now override values from the template - see my answer for how it can now work. This presents no compatibility risk, as this scenario would always have failed in an exception previously.

Comment: @Marc happy to help. The `Add` did indeed replace the value and worked with the template as I've shown in my code. Could you explain what tweak was needed? To me it looked like values were being replaced already, so the tweak is unclear to me since our approaches appear to be identical. The only difference is I didn't show the usage of the template, I just explained it and the code continues after that. Thanks!

Comment: @Ahmed if you *generate from a template* (for convenience), then use `Add`, then those got added twice (not replaced). The use of a template is a significant factor here, and I assume the OP wants to use the template approach to reduce overhead. You can see the change [in this diff](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/diff?spec=svnf600f226a0cca1c9a293472f577d8ad2a7f44885&old=8270d9a07d1fe4501b8f398ec17a21ae80d99341&r=f600f226a0cca1c9a293472f577d8ad2a7f44885&format=unidiff&path=%2FDapper%2FSqlMapper.cs)

Comment: @Marc I see what you're referring to now. I didn't look closely at the code, specifically `AddParameters`, rather I was looking at the `Add` method on `DynamicParameters` that assigns directly to the private `parameters` dictionary. Thanks for clearing that up! BTW, are you guys following a certain NuGet release schedule or is it behind? I just noticed NuGet has v1.6 which was last updated in July 2011. Anyway, keep up the good work :)

Comment: @AhmadMageed I've pushed 1.7 to nuget